# Should meta tag fb:admins include the app:id number as well?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I developed an application which produces many open graph instances. Each of these instances has a like button and a connect forum.

In my meta I specify my app:id and fb knows I am an admin for every forum. I can store the facebook ID of each of the open graph instances (my customers) and set app:admins as a meta tag.

1. If I set app:admins, do I need to include my own ID? Will FB still know I own the app and have admin rights if I don't include my own ID? I would prefer not to have to add my own ID to each og instance.
2. In initial testing I found that og didn't seem to work for me if I used both app:id and app:admins meta tags but I was not able to thoroughly test it before I gave up and just went with app:id.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want you should just use the fb:app_id in your Open Graph tags. Any admins can be added as admins of your app in the Dev App. You could also have a separate app for each customer.